# PHP: convert an EBCDIC binary file with compression into ASCII format

Tags: php, type-conversion, file-conversion, unpack, ebcdic

I am looking for PHP code that can convert an EBCDIC binary file in to ASCII. This EBCDIC file also has some packed data fields, the code should be able to unpack these fields as well, and present them in a readable format.

EBCDIC files follow the **CP037** format.

The file has the following definition. As you can see below the first compressed value starts after the 7th char and is 18 char long.

```
  ******************************************************************
  * COBOL DECLARATION FOR TABLE CUST_BILL                          *
  ******************************************************************
  01  DCL-CUST-BILL.
      10 FILLER                          PIC X(05).
      10 TB01196-BL-TYP-CD               PIC X(2).
      10 TB01196-INVOICE-NO              PIC S9(18) COMP.
      10 TB01196-CUST-ID-NO              PIC S9(9) COMP.
      10 TB01196-ACCT-NO                 PIC S9(9) COMP.
      10 TB01196-BL-CYC-NO               PIC X(2).
      10 TB01196-CYC-MTH-YR              PIC X(6).
      10 TB01196-JOB-ITERATION-NO        PIC S9(4) COMP.
      10 TB01196-BL-DISC-APLIED-PCT PIC S9(5)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-PREV-INV-RM-AMT PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-PMT-MADE-AMT PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-TOT-CUR-CHG PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-TOT-REMIT-AMT PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-PEND-IND             PIC X(1).
      10 TB01196-BL-FED-EX-TX  PIC S9(7)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-ST-LCL-SLS-TX PIC S9(7)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-OTH-TX     PIC S9(7)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BAL-FORWARD-AMT PIC S9(9)V9(2) COMP-3.
      10 TB01196-BL-PRINTED-IND          PIC X(1).
      10 TB01196-DB-USERID               PIC X(8).
      10 TB01196-DB-TMSTAMP              PIC X(26).
      10 CUST-ACCT-INT-SRVC-CHG          PIC S9(7)V99 COMP-3.
  ******************************************************************
  * THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS DESCRIBED BY THIS DECLARATION IS 20      *
  ******************************************************************
```

This is represantation of the EBCIDIC:
[image: This is represantation of the EBCIDIC]

This is the converted ASCII format which I'm trying to achieve:
[image: this is the converted ASCII format which I'm trying to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

In general you can decode/unpack in PHP using the unpack function, though my experience is that it's quite time consuming to get it right;
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

This question has some answers (in particular sharing the code for EBCDIC to ASCII) which you may find a useful starting point:
[php - convert ebcdic to ascii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499656/php-convert-ebcdic-to-ascii)